# CreateApplicationBuilder and passing command line arguments

Tags: .net

I am writing a long running command line application and using CreateApplicationBuilder class and CommandLineParser for command line arguments.

I need to parse arguments in main and provide it to my ClientHostedService class where I call CommandLineParser which needs as string[]. The IConfiguration doesnt seem to give me the command line arguments in this format. Is there a way to do this?

```
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddHostedService<ClientHostedService>();
     ....
   
    IHost host =builder.Build();        
    await host.StartAsync();
    await host.StopAsync();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at parsing here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of `CreateApplicationBuilder` that doesn't take the CLI args. Passing the CLI to `CreateApplicationBuilder` is purely to pass to the [command line configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#command-line-configuration-provider) which parses those command line args to appear as a source for `IConfiguration`. But there is no requirement for this.

Instead you can do your own command line processing (directly of via a library).

IMHO this makes far more sense that the `IConfiguration` approach for a command line tool. (I have tried to combine, but it is, at best, messy.)

Answer (score 0):

Commandlineparser library is mature and decent in doing its job. I ended up with the following solution and posting for anybody as a future reference

1. I created an InMemoryCollection as IConfiguration with providing a section name for the Keys for Dictionary.

```
builder.Configuration.AddInMemoryCollection(Utilities.GetDictionaryFromArguments(args,"CommandLine"));
```

2.With the following function

```
        public static Dictionary<string, string?> GetDictionaryFromArguments(string[] args,string Prefix)
    {
        var Mappings = new Dictionary<string, string?>();
        for (int key=0; key<args.Length; key++)
        {
            Mappings.Add(Prefix +":"+ key, args[key]);
        }
        return Mappings;
    }
```

3. Pass IConfiguration to ClientHostedService
4. Get IConfiguration Items with GetSection

```
List<IConfigurationSection> items = _configuration.GetSection("CommandLine").GetChildren().ToList();
```

5. Convert IConfiguration to string[]

```
        
public static string[] GetArgumentsFromIConfigurationSection(List<IConfigurationSection> list)
    {
        string[] result = new string[list.Count];
        int count = 0;
        foreach(var Pair in list)
        {
            result[count]=Pair.Value;
            count++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

6. Finally pass string[] to Commandlineparser.